# Clickoutside event doen't work on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-frontend

It's a  rich-text editor,there is a div show the content users typed in, just like this:

```
<div class=‘content’>
    <iframe data-role=text-editable.></iframe>
</div>
```

When i click a icon who's used to call the color panel，the  panel will show.And i wish when i click outside the panel,it will be hide.so my code is:

```
var  color_panel = $('.color-panel');
     color_panel.on("clickoutside",        function (e) {                   
    var t = $(e.target);            
    if ($.contains(color_panel[0], t[0]))                  
        return;   
    color_panel.hide();
})
```

It  works well when   i   click outside  the panel will disappear  except i click the iframe.when i click the ifame,nothing happens,the panel is still shown,

Help......i  want to know the reason .please...is the ifame not  the dom element outside the panel?

Comment: `color-panel` isn't valid variable name in javascript. Which language are you coding???

Comment: sorry . the symbol "-"should be ''_",it's underline

Comment: I'm assuming your jQuery selector `$('color-panel')`  is intending to select a class or an id? It should be `$('.color-panel') ` or `$('#color-panel') `.

Comment: You have to provide the relevant code you are using, not some random one full of typos. That's said, you cannot capture click on cross domain iframe but i'm unsure this has to do with your question

Comment: You have fancy quotes, that is a bug.

Comment: Do you have a library for clickoutside since that is some custom event not in jQuery? Where is the code running, inside the iframe?

Comment: hey thank you everyone,the code is not pasted from my editor.

Comment: thank you all of you .the code is typed by my phone ,so a few mistake  i 've made,i can not use my computer temporary .sorry.let's focus on the problem

Comment: @epascarello yes,it's part of a  project,clickoutside is defined here

Comment: @A.Wolff i am so sorry.Maybe tomorrow i will paste the code for you.it's not right to type code by iphone

Comment: Is the code running inside the iframe? What is ".color-panel" in relationship with that html you showed? Is color panel inside the iframe? When you bind the event is color-panel actually loaded?

Comment: @epascarello No,it is not running in the iframe,in fact,i simplify the question,we know a rich text editor ,often there are some options ,some to change the style of the text,color ,underline...and so on. the ifame is below the option icons,to show what the texts are look like now.And the color panel is used by users to choose color .Sorry sir ,my english is so poor and i wonder whether you can get it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: So what does `console.log("I found: ", $('.color-panel').length);` show in the developer console? If it shows zero, than there is your problem. If it shows a number, than the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @epascarello It will be a number sir,i strongly believe it's the ifame which lead to this situation

Comment: Well the iframe eats clicks so the parent will not get the click event.

Comment: @epascarello sorry,i have to sleep,cause it's 1:00 am in my country.Thank you for your help sir, i wish wheather we could discuss the issue about 7hours later(╯3╰)

Comment: Listen for a click on iframe and not just outside.

Comment: hi，everyone .i noticed that the problem is ，when i click the iframe,i can't capture the click event!For example,when i console.log(e.target),there's nothing when i click the iframe.i wonder how can i capture the click event from the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for outside clicks by listening for clicks on the body element of the webpage (so, clicking on anything element) and then you can exclude your `.color_panel` from this event by making another event that says "when I get clicked on, ignore any other clicks". The effect will be exactly what you want, that you can listen for outside clicks:

```
var panelOpen = false;

$('body').click(function(event) {
  if (panelOpen) {
    panelOpen = false;
    color_panel.hide();
  }
});

$('.color_panel').click(function(event) {
  panelOpen = true;
  //callYourMethodToShowThePanelHere();
  e.preventDefault(); // these methods will stop the body click event
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: hi，good answer,and i learn a lot.But in this project i can't modify the code so much.i noticed that the problem is ，when i click the iframe,i  can't capture the click event!For example,when i console.log(e.target),there's nothing when i click the iframe

Comment: thank You man,the problem is solved.The matter is the event in  iframe itself can not be captured by the parent window,so i need modify the  code like this: